# Drag and drop prevent multiple item to move at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I've got, in a UIScrollview, multiple custom subviews which inherit from UIView and which are draggable. Everything works fine with it except that i'm able to drag two or more subviews at the same time. The gesture recognizer are attached to my custom subviews and implemented inside this class. 
Is there any way to prevent this behavior ?

EDIT : I've already tried to add in the delegate

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
return false
}
```

But it's not working since all the subviews handle themselves their own gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

The `GestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol has a function to specify whether multiple gesture recognizers can act simultaneously. I don't know if that works in your case but it is worth a try:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but since the gesture delegate and code is in the subviews, i seem to don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but I came across the same problem where I want only one item to be draggable at same time. You can loop through all your draggable subviews and update their properties as below.

```
           subiew.isExclusiveTouch = true
    subview.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
```

Now only one subview will be draggable at same time.

Comment: This question is 7 years old. It most likely doesn't need an answer anymore, and the versions used changed.

Comment: @Gugu72 I came across this issue today. I tried searching for an answer but I couldn't find it anywhere. So, when I found the answer, I posted it, for someone who might be looking for it. Versions may change but the logic doesn't.